# Did Thomas Sharpe know who Edith was, that the stack of pages on her desk was a manuscript and that she had written it?

Tags: crimson-peak

When Thomas initially meets Edith, he's actually late for a meeting with her father. He stops at Edith's desk on the way to her father's office; I think he was asking for directions.

He notices a stack of papers on the desk in front of her, he picks them up and immediately knows it's a manuscript to be transcribed, a work of fiction, a ghost story and that he really likes it.

Was that whole discussion, and the arranged meeting with Edith's father, all a part of the Sharpe's plan to trick Edith into marrying Thomas and already Thomas knew a great deal about Edith and the fact she was a struggling author?

Or did Thomas just figure all this out on the spot in 2 or 3 seconds?

It's never really mentioned in the movie.

> **Thomas**: I don't mean to pry,
>   but this is a piece
>   of fiction, is it not?
>
> **Edith**: Yes.
>
> **Thomas**: Who are you transcribing this for?
>
> **Edith**: It's to be sent to New York tomorrow,
>   to The Atlantic Monthly.
>
> **Thomas**: Well, whoever wrote it,
>   it's rather good,
>   don't you think?
>
> **Edith**: Really?
>
> **Thomas**: It's certainly captured my attention.
>
> **Edith**: I wrote it. It's mine.
>
> **Thomas**: Ghosts?
>
> **Edith**: Well, the ghosts are
>   just a metaphor...

Comment: The film got a novelisation, by the way. It may shed some light on what you're concerned about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Probably not

Sharpe’s original plan was not to marry Edith at all, but Eunice. He and Edith married out of genuine emotion on both sides:

> He had planned to court Eunice McMichael, but there were…
> complications. And once he had met Edith, he had been dazzled by her,
> as a moth is stunned and lured by candlelight. She was as golden as
> the sun, and he could not help but turn his face to her.
>
> <sub>*Crimson Peak* (novelization)</sub>

Not to mention, he really did have a machine that needed funding. As such, he probably didn’t know much about Edith, least of all that her manuscript was a ghost story.

And as far as Thomas reading the manuscript, it would seem that he really did. The scene is a bit different in the book (for example, not all the dialogue is there), but it does clearly describe Thomas as reading the manuscript:

> “I’m sorry, I don’t mean to pry. But—” he gestured at her manuscript,
> and she realized then that **he’d craned his neck in order to read it**
> “—this is a piece of fiction, is it not?”
>
> She nodded, concealing her consternation. She wanted to explain that
> the ghost was a metaphor, and to assure him that she had already
> decided that it was just too silly for the heroine to fall in love
> with Cavendish on page one and she was going to change it back to the
> way it had been before Ogilvie had turned it down. She shouldn’t have
> listened to him, even if he was a famous publisher. Love stories were
> fairy tales and lies as far as she was concerned and… good Lord, he
> was reading more of it.
>
> “Who are you transcribing this for?” he asked, genuinely interested.
> But she couldn’t tell if he was intrigued or horrified by the text on
> the page.
>
> She decided to dodge his question. If he hated it, that would be
> altogether mortifying. “It’s to be sent to New York tomorrow. The
> Atlantic Monthly.”
>
> He took that in. **Read another page.** “Well, whoever wrote this is quite
> good, don’t you think?”
>
> <sub>*Crimson Peak* (novelization)</sub>